# Background process is not picking input in Linux if not waiting

Tags: php, linux, child-process

I am doing a project with the following specs:

1. User inputs some data, including someone's phone number.
2. The system makes some computations based on the user input and saves result in DB.
3. If 2 succeeds, sms is sent, through some API call, to the phone number included in 1
4. User does not have to wait for 3 to conclude before being notified of success in 2.

Now, because of nature of 3 above, I passed it to some background process through proc_open. The problem is, if I include '&' in the command from the main process like as follows:

```
    $descriptorspec = array(
                0=>array("pipe","r"),
                1=>array("file", "log.txt", "a" ),
                2=>array("file", "log.txt", "a" )
            );

   $command = 'php smschildprocess.php &';
   $input = 'some text input';
   $proc = proc_open( $command, $descriptorspec, $pipes );
   fwrite($pipes[0], $input);
   fclose($pipes[0]);
   proc_close($proc);
```

and attempt to get the input from the child process like this :

```
$input = stream_get_contents(STDIN);
```

The variable `$input` just has blank space. Whereas if the trailing `&` is removed from the command, I get the input at the child process but it blocks the main process.

Just to add, this problem only occurs on production server which is a Linux box, but on my development machine, a windows box, I do something like `$command = 'start /b php smschildprocess.php';` everything works just fine whether non-blocking with `start /b` or otherwise without `start /b`
I have spent days looking at docs and example codes, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you trying to do it inline, put it on a job queue.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, that sounds like a good alternative. But I still need to know what has gone wrong. Thanks, though.